# How do I start a Jquery get request from within a php script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a gallery with a large image slider and a small grid of thumbnails working in php but I need a javascript function to swap and reuse this function to interactively load the new images and thumbnails. How would I pass the start parameter to a Jquery function to fill the image slider and the grid? Currently I'm writing a href to the document with the start parameter and in the document.load function I scrap this href und fire a getjson function to pull the records from my database?

Here is my Jquery, it looks for the first href in my menu li document subtree and use it as get parameter to pull the records from my database:

```
   $j("#tx-gallery-pi1 #menu li").click(function() {  
     $j.getJSON($j(this).find('a').attr('href'), function(json) {
    var container = $j('#tx-gallery-pi1 #container');
    container.masonry();
    $j.each(json, function(idx, ele) {
      container.append($j("#brickTemplate").tmpl(ele).css({
        "display": "block"
      })).masonry('reload');

      container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        // bricks correct height
        var brick = $j("#tx-gallery-pi1 #container .brick"); 
        brick.each(function() {
          var content = $j(this).find(">div");
          var img = $j(this).find("img");
           content.css({
            height: img.attr("height")
           });
        });
      });
    });
  });
  return false; // don't follow the link!
});
```

}

Comment: Can you give us some code please?

Comment: just echo out the parameter into the jQuery code using a <?php echo something; ?> tag

Comment: To me your solution looks perfectly valid if you want to completely separate php code from javascript. You could use a hidden input instead of the anchor. Another option, less strict in terms of separation, is to output a `<script>` block with PHP, and set a global variable inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create an HTML document with php, you can say

```
<script>
    var startvar ='<?php echo($yourvariable); ?>';
</script>
```

and use it later on in the site.

You can update your output document using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

you should split that php in different actions on your controller (like get_thumbnails and get_image with the html code for each part) and using jQuery you can do "$(thumbnails_container).load('/get_thumbnails.php')", it would be easier to answer if you put at least the relevant code

check the jQuery's load method's docs if you need post or get parameters

Comment: Yes, what is with the parameters?

Comment: you can pass get parameters directyl on the url: "$(container).load('url.php?paramater1=value1&parameter2=value2'), and post parameters should be a hash with {param:value} passed in a second argument for the function load, if you have that hash, then the request is automatically a post request.